# Selenium WebDriver with C# - How can I locate these buttons?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to click on each of these buttons but I'm failing to get anything.  Even xpath is failing to pick them up.  Does anyone have any idea on how to locate these buttons?

```
<button class="rt-button rt-dialog-button" title="" value="">Close</button>
<button class="rt-button rt-dialog-button" title="" value="">OK</button>
```

Many thanks for any help

**EDIT:**

Thanks for trying to help.  None of the suggestions worked for me but I did sort it out using:

c#

```
IWebElement OKButton = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(("//button[@class='rt-button rt-dialog-button'][2]")));

IWebElement CloseButton = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(("//button[@class='rt-button rt-dialog-button'][1]")));
```

Comment: It would be good if you can share the code what you have tried and what you have got (output/error)?

Comment: Well **what XPath are you using in the first place**?!!!!

Answer (score 3):

I'd use xpath to find them:

```
By.XPath("//button[text()='Close']")
By.XPath("//button[text()='OK']")
```

Comment: Thanks Richard.  That would normally work for me but didn't in this case for some reason

Comment: @Banjaxx What is happening?  `NoSuchElementException`, or some other error?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an ID, to each element.

```
<button id="closeButton" class="rt-button rt-dialog-button" title="" value="">Close</button>
<button id="okButton" class="rt-button rt-dialog-button" title="" value="">OK</button>
```

Then to find it you can do something like

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("closeButton"));
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("openButton"));
```

I have had times where I was having a hard time with capturing by class and x-path and ID helped.

Comment: Thanks for helping.  I don't have access to the code so I'm not able to apply ID's to elements.  Nice idea though :)

Comment: No problem, @Banjaxx. I am glad that you got it all sorted out. Selenium can be quirky sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this xpath:

```
//button[contains(text(),'Close')]
```

Comment: Thank you.  Should have worked but for some reason didn't seem to

Answer (score 0):

//[.='OK']

if this does not work then you have multiple elements having same text hidden or somewhere on the page

Comment: Thanks for that.  This could be the reason why